# How can I check is a number is a Dudeney Number, using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I check if a number is a Dudeney Number, using Ruby? Taking as examples or evidence, these results:

```
dudeney_number?(1)     #=> true
dudeney_number?(125)   #=> false
dudeney_number?(512)   #=> true
dudeney_number?(1728)  #=> false
dudeney_number?(5832)  #=> true
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What exactly is your question? "As I can check" doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudeney_number:

> A Dudeney number is a positive integer that is a perfect cube such that the sum of its decimal digits is equal to the cube root of the number.

Here's an implementation by that definition:

```
def dudeney_number?(n)
  digit_sum = n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
  n == digit_sum ** 3
end

1.upto(20000).select { |n| dudeney_number? n }
#=> [1, 512, 4913, 5832, 17576, 19683]
```

The method doesn't check if `n` is a positive integer.

Answer (score 5):

Well, that's easy; there are only 6!

```
def dudeney_number?(x)
    return [1, 512, 4913, 5832, 17576, 19683].include?(x)
end
```

See also: http://blog.hostilefork.com/six-dudeney-numbers-proof/